# Is there any way to detect modulation from midi using Music21?

Tags: python, music21

I have this code, as part of a project to read and interpret a MIDI file:

```
midi_data = m21.converter.parse(midi_file)
key = midi_data.analyze('key')
print(key.name)
```

I need to get the key information. With this code, the first key is shown, but it does not correspond to a modulation.

How can I detect modulations?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and also try starting with the documentation. I [edit]ed the question to fix the code [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and to [remove noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721). Note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; we do not want sign-offs or greetings, we do want a *clear, explicit question*.

Comment: Does https://groups.google.com/g/music21list/c/kzHBtB437lc?pli=1 help? I found it by putting `music21 key modulation` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=music21+key+modulation). [Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) to research questions before asking.

Comment: @peter Thank you for answering and editing my question.
Unfortunately, the link you sent me didn't help.
This is because it was not a direct detection method from midi, but an algorithmic one.
I will continue to look into this myself.
Thanks again.